# Velocity "undefined" in es6 class constructor (using npm & browserify)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, velocity, browserify

I am trying to use velocity, installed with npm and included with browserify:

```
var React = require('react'),
    velocity_animate = require('velocity-animate'),
    libMessageTemplates = require('../modules/message_templates');
    debugger; // velocity_animate loaded successfully, !== undefined
```

At the debugger ^ on line 4 above, the library exists.

Then, I create my react component

```
class Messages {
    constructor () {
        document.getElementById('a').velocity_animate("scroll");
        debugger; // velocity_animate === undefined
    }
}

new Messages();
```

At this point, velocity_animate is undefined??

Comment: Not enough information to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Seems as if it doesn't work in any es6 class...

Comment: What more information do you need? I've tried to isolate the problem to the least amount of possible variables for this question.

Comment: `velocity_animate` is not used in the method, so chrome optimises and does not capture it.

Comment: In the live code I use velocity_animate. I've added a use to the question, but I don't believe chrome would optimize to change the scoping of the language.

Comment: Can't repro: http://jsfiddle.net/5mxvqhz0/

Comment: Thank you for trying. I'll have to look more into my own environment.

Comment: It does optimise that. And you haven't added using the `velocity_animate` variable.

Comment: Hey guys, just got to work on Monday and decided to start from the beginning... now it works. Thank you for all of the help.